# Jumping times of a Lévy Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times, levy-processes

If one has a Levy-process, are the times when the process has a jump of size exceeding a positive $\varepsilon$ actually stopping times w.r.t. the canonical filtration?

In more detail: Let $X=(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a Levy process (it especially has a.s. cadlag paths) and $\varepsilon>0$. Then define the times $T_{\varepsilon}^{(0)}(X):=0$ and $T_{\varepsilon}^{(i+1)}(X):=\inf\{t>T_{\varepsilon}^{(i)}(X):|\Delta X_t|>\varepsilon\}$, where $\Delta X_t:=X_{t}-X_{t-}$ denotes a possible jump and $\inf\emptyset:=\infty$. Take the canonical (wlog. augmented) filtration $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(X_s,s\leq t)$. Question: Are the times $T_{\varepsilon}^{(i)}(X)$ stopping times?

My idea so far: Given $T_{\varepsilon}^{(1)}$ is a stopping time, one can write $T_{\varepsilon}^{(2)}(X)=T_{\varepsilon}^{(1)}(X)+T_{\varepsilon}^{(1)}(X\circ\theta_{T_{\varepsilon}^{(i)}(X)})$, where $\theta_T$ denotes the shift-operator (tbh I'm not sure if this is true at all, but I guess one could use the fact that $X$ has independent increments to prove this?) If that was true, it would suffice to show that $T_{\varepsilon}^{(1)}(X)$ is a stopping time. At this point I'm pretty clueless, since the condition $|\Delta X_t|>\varepsilon$ is rather hard to handle I guess?

Maybe some Markov-arguments may apply? Though it bothers me that the paths are not continuous. Some ideas? References? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows indeed from the Markov property (...which is a consequence of the independence of the increments) that it suffices to show the claim for $i=1$.

Let $t>0$, $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $|\Delta X_t(\omega)| > \varepsilon$. Since $X$ has (a.s.) càdlàg sample paths, we can find for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ sufficiently large some $r_k, s_k \in \mathbb{Q}$, $t - 1/k \leq r_k \leq t \leq s_k \leq t+ 1/k$, such that

$$|X_{s_k}(\omega)-X_{r_k}(\omega)| > \varepsilon.$$

Consequently,

$$\{|\Delta X_t|>\varepsilon\} \subseteq \bigcup_{\ell \geq 1} \bigcap_{k \geq \ell} \bigcup_{\substack{r_k,s_k \in \mathbb{Q} \\ t-1/k \leq r_k \leq t \leq s_k \leq t+1/k}} \{|X_{s_k}-X_{r_k}|>\varepsilon\}. \tag{1}$$

Hence,

$$\{T_{\varepsilon}^{(1)}(X) < t\} = \bigcup_{\ell \geq 1} \bigcap_{k \geq \ell} \bigcup_{\substack{r_k,s_k \in \mathbb{Q} \\ |r_k-s_k| \leq 2/k, r_k \leq s_k <t}} \{|X_{s_k}-X_{r_k}|>\varepsilon\}=:A. \tag{2}$$

On the other hand, it is not difficult to see that $\omega \in A$ implies $\omega \in \{T_{\varepsilon}^{(1)} < t\}$. Since $A \in \mathcal{F}_t$ (it is a countable union of $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable sets), we conclude that

$$\{T_{\varepsilon}^{(1)}(X) \leq t\} = \{T_{\varepsilon}^{(1)}(X) < t\} \cup \{|\Delta X_t|>\varepsilon\} \in \mathcal{F}_t.$$

(Note that $(1)$ shows that $\{|\Delta X_t|>\varepsilon\} \in \mathcal{F}_{t+}$; but if do not require $s_k \in \mathbb{Q}$, we can set $s_k = t$ and find that $\{|\Delta X_t|>\varepsilon\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$.)

**Remark:** The proof shows that the claim does not only hold for Lévy processes, but for càdlàg (strong) Markov processes.

Comment: +1 Thank you for this great and detailed answer! You know any good references, where I may look up more about similar results on stopping times of Levy processes or similar?

Comment: @Mr.Barrrington Unfortunately, I don't know any good references on this topic - it seems to me that there is a gap between books which are easily accessible (... and don't bother the reader with this technical stuff) and specialized books (... where the reader is supposed to know this "basic" technical stuff).

Comment: @Did Do you know any good references? :)

Comment: How did you find $r_k,s_k$ in the second paragraph? Please take a look at the question I've asked for this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4292727/47771.